# Switch ubuntu graphics driver

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics

I had an install of ubuntu on an old hard drive in a computer with a nvidia graphics chipset in it. I just moved the drive to a new computer with an amd card, and I am having troubles switching over. I have to boot into shell mode, and then change the driver section of device in xorg.conf to vesa to get it to boot gnome in safe graphics mode. From there I can install the catalyst/fglrx driver, and then restart when it is finished to finalize the changes. When I reboot however, it fails to do anything, so I have to repeat the process. The contents of xorg.conf actually get reverted back to the nvidia settings after the driver install. How can I install the drivers and get it working?
Contents of device section of xorg.conf:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 240"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 240"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection
```

Comment: I would recommend running `amdcccle` when you are able to boot into the graphics mode.

Comment: Running from the safe mode with the drivers set to vesa? I will try it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That makes no difference `amdcccle` is the native configuration tool for AMD/ATI cards it will create the configuration for you.  As long as you have the `fglrx` and `fglrx-amdcccle` packages installed.

Comment: I got it working. I had to boot into safemode, then remove all graphics drivers, and then manually install amds.